# How to get multiple multirows in a table?

Tags: tables, multirow

I want to render a table with results of experiments. There are 6 experiments (multirows) described by 2 columns and each of them is performed 5 times (rows).

My code:

```
\begin{tabular}{l r | l || r r}
Vzorka & Výskyty & Algoritmus & Porovnania & Prístupy \\ \hline 
\multirow{5}{*}{Gabriel} & \multirow{5}{*}{8}
& NAIVE BINARY          & 158   & 44 \& NAIVE BINARY_LCP      & 174 & 92 \& NAIVE INTERPOLATION   & 168 & 78 \& LESS NAIVE BINARY       & 98    & 26 \& LESS NAIVE BINARY_LCP & 124   & 58 \\ \hline
...
\end{tabular}
```

This code produces what I want only for the first row:

[image: The output of above code]

successful rows after the first one are shifted and overlapping the "8" number.
Can you please help me?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe your problem is that you didn't put enough empty cells for the following lines.
A multirow will allow content to occupy space, but doesn't actually create the cells that are under it.  I rewrote your code aligning everything to illustrate that.

```
\begin{tabular}{l r | l || r r}
Vzorka & Výskyty & Algoritmus & Porovnania & Prístupy \\ \hline 
\multirow{5}{*}{Gabriel} & \multirow{5}{*}{8} & NAIVE BINARY          & 158   & 44 \\
                         &                    & NAIVE BINARY_LCP      & 174   & 92 \\
                         &                    & NAIVE INTERPOLATION   & 168   & 78 \\
                         &                    & LESS NAIVE BINARY     & 98    & 26 \\
                         &                    & LESS NAIVE BINARY_LCP & 124   & 58 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 3):

You may also typeset the table without [multicols](https://ctan.org/pkg/multirow), using nested tabular. The nested tabulars are put inside two new commands, `\splitl` and `\splitr`.

The main tabular is set using `tabular*`, to ensure better distribution of space. The benefit using nested table is that LaTeX does most of the calculation.

To improve readability, I suggest that you consider to remove most of the vertical line (see example 2).

**`tabular*` and `hline`**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.1}

% Multi-line left-aligned text with manual line breaks.
% The base line is in centre.
\newcommand*{\splitl}[1]{%
\begingroup
    \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.1}%
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}%
  \endgroup
}

% Multi-line right-aligned text with manual line breaks.
% The base line is in centre.

\newcommand*{\splitr}[1]{%
\begingroup
    \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.1}%
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}r@{}}#1\end{tabular}%
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand{\smb}{\small\bfseries}


\begin{document}


\noindent\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|l c | l ||rr|}

\smb Vzorka & \smb Výskyty & \smb Algoritmus & \smb Porovnania & \smb Prístupy \\ \hline 
Gabriel & 8 &\splitl{NAIVE BINARY \\
                                   NAIVE BINARY \\
                                   NAIVE INTERPOLATION\\
                                   LESS NAIVE BINARY \\
                                   LESS NAIVE BINARY\_LCP
                                   } & 
                                   \splitr{158 \\
                                           174 \\
                                           168 \\
                                           98  \\
                                           124} &
                                           \splitr{44\\
                                                      92\\
                                                      78\\
                                                      26 \\
                                                      59
                                                      }\\

\hline
``father'' & 8 &\splitl{NAIVE BINARY \\
                                   NAIVE BINARY \\
                                   NAIVE INTERPOLATION\\
                                   LESS NAIVE BINARY \\
                                   LESS NAIVE BINARY\_LCP
                                   } & 
                                   \splitr{202 \\
                                           187 \\
                                           101 \\
                                           179  \\
                                           169} &
                                           \splitr{45\\
                                                      94\\
                                                      40\\
                                                      37 \\
                                                      80
                                                      }\\

\hline
``God'' & 8    &\splitl{NAIVE BINARY \\
                                   NAIVE BINARY \\
                                   NAIVE INTERPOLATION\\
                                   LESS NAIVE BINARY \\
                                   LESS NAIVE BINARY\_LCP
                                   } & 
                                   \splitr{142 \\
                                           154 \\
                                          2472 \\
                                           119  \\
                                           128} &
                                           \splitr{45\\
                                                    94\\
                                                  1240\\
                                                    35 \\
                                                    76
                                                      }\\

\hline
``Mary'' & 8    &\splitl{NAIVE BINARY \\
                                   NAIVE BINARY \\
                                   NAIVE INTERPOLATION\\
                                   LESS NAIVE BINARY \\
                                   LESS NAIVE BINARY\_LCP
                                   } & 
                                   \splitr{147 \\
                                           154 \\
                                           191 \\
                                           106 \\
                                           115} &
                                           \splitr{45\\
                                                      94\\
                                                      88\\
                                                      29\\
                                                      64
                                                      }\\

\hline
``Ezechiel'' & 8    &\splitl{NAIVE BINARY \\
                                   NAIVE BINARY \\
                                   NAIVE INTERPOLATION\\
                                   LESS NAIVE BINARY \\
                                   LESS NAIVE BINARY\_LCP
                                   } & 
                                   \splitr{175 \\
                                           181 \\
                                           886 \\
                                           133 \\
                                           142} &
                                           \splitr{44\\
                                                      92\\
                                                     230\\
                                                      28\\
                                                      63
                                                      }\\

\hline
\end{tabular*}
\end{document}
```

**`tabular*` and [booktabs](https://ctan.org/pkg/multirow)**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.1}

% Multi-line left-aligned text with manual line breaks.
% The base line is in centre.
\newcommand*{\splitl}[1]{%
\begingroup
    \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.1}%
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}%
  \endgroup
}

% Multi-line right-aligned text with manual line breaks.
% The base line is in centre.

\newcommand*{\splitr}[1]{%
\begingroup
    \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.1}%
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}r@{}}#1\end{tabular}%
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand{\smb}{\small\bfseries}


\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l c  l  rr@{}}

\toprule
\smb Vzorka & \smb Výskyty & \smb Algoritmus & \smb Porovnania & \smb Prístupy \\ \midrule 
Gabriel & 8 &\splitl{NAIVE BINARY \\
                                   NAIVE BINARY \\
                                   NAIVE INTERPOLATION\\
                                   LESS NAIVE BINARY \\
                                   LESS NAIVE BINARY\_LCP
                                   } & 
                                   \splitr{158 \\
                                           174 \\
                                           168 \\
                                           98  \\
                                           124
                                           } &
                                           \splitr{44\\
                                                   92\\
                                                   78\\
                                                   26\\
                                                   59
                                               }\\

\midrule
``father'' & 8 &\splitl{NAIVE BINARY \\
                                   NAIVE BINARY \\
                                   NAIVE INTERPOLATION\\
                                   LESS NAIVE BINARY \\
                                   LESS NAIVE BINARY\_LCP
                                   } & 
                                   \splitr{202 \\
                                           187 \\
                                           101 \\
                                           179  \\
                                           169} &
                                           \splitr{45\\
                                                   94\\
                                                   40\\
                                                   37 \\
                                                   80
                                                }\\

\midrule
``God'' & 8    &\splitl{NAIVE BINARY \\
                                   NAIVE BINARY \\
                                   NAIVE INTERPOLATION\\
                                   LESS NAIVE BINARY \\
                                   LESS NAIVE BINARY\_LCP
                                   } & 
                                   \splitr{142 \\
                                           154 \\
                                          2472 \\
                                           119  \\
                                           128} &
                                           \splitr{45\\
                                                   94\\
                                                  1240\\
                                                    35\\
                                                    76
                                                }\\

\midrule
``Mary'' & 8    &\splitl{NAIVE BINARY \\
                                   NAIVE BINARY \\
                                   NAIVE INTERPOLATION\\
                                   LESS NAIVE BINARY \\
                                   LESS NAIVE BINARY\_LCP
                                   } & 
                                   \splitr{147 \\
                                           154 \\
                                           191 \\
                                           106  \\
                                           115} &
                                           \splitr{45\\
                                                   94\\
                                                   88\\
                                                   29\\
                                                   64
                                                }\\

\midrule
``Ezechiel'' & 8    &\splitl{NAIVE BINARY \\
                                   NAIVE BINARY \\
                                   NAIVE INTERPOLATION\\
                                   LESS NAIVE BINARY \\
                                   LESS NAIVE BINARY\_LCP
                                   } & 
                                   \splitr{175 \\
                                           181 \\
                                           886 \\
                                           133 \\
                                           142} &
                                           \splitr{44\\
                                                   92\\
                                                  230\\
                                                   28\\
                                                   63
                                                }\\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{document}
```