# How to do a table with multiple multirows_

Tags: tables, multirow

I've just started to work with latex. I'm aware of the post [How to get multiple multirows in a table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21728/how-to-get-multiple-multirows-in-a-table) but still with it I don't manage to do with my table what I'd like.
Basically I'd like to get two multirow cells, one at the beginning and one at the end. It'd also be great if I could vertically center the text and align it to the left (if I set the width I don't know how to do this). 
There's a last thing I'd also like to do but it's not so important. This is to remove the exterior lines of the only empty cell in my table.

This is the code I've been working with:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | p{3cm} | p{3cm} | p{3cm} | p{5cm} |}
\hline
    & 
    Text1 & 
    Text2 & 
    Notes \\ 
\hline
    \multirow{2}{*}
    {Multirow two} &
    Soil &
    Water &
    This should also be multirow (like the first column) \\
    \hline
    &
    Water retention curve $\sin$150g &
    Water retention curve $\sin$200 g 
    & \\
\hline
    This is ok &
    ok &
    ok &
    ok \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a way to achieve what you want. It uses the `array`, `tabularx` and `makecell` package. I use the `\multirowcell` command, from `makecell`, which has a simpler syntax than `multirow`. Note that when you use \multirow, you must count the number of *lines* and not the number of cells if some cells are multilined.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}

    \usepackage{array, booktabs, tabularx,makecell}
    \renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
    \renewcommand\cellalign{Xc}

    \begin{document}

    \vspace*{1\baselineskip}
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}\linewidth{ | *{3}{ >{\raggedright}m{2.8cm}|} X |}
    \cline{2-4}
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}  & Text1 & Text2 & Notes \\
    \hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{Multirow two} & Soil & Water & \multirowcell{3}{This should also be multirow (like the first column)} \\
    \cline{2-3}
    & Water retention curve $\sin$\,150\,g & Water retention curve $\sin$\,200\,g  & \\
    \hline
    This is ok & ok & ok & ok \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! This is a big help to keep learning from this point!

Comment: You're welcome. Think of taking a look at the packages documentation, you'learn a lot of things.

Comment: There's a little mistake when giving the linewidth: it says 2.8Acm instead of just 2.8cm.

Comment: That's a typo. I thought I had deleted and didn't check. Thanks.